# Group By using Select statement in Linq

Tags: c#, sql, linq, c#-4.0

```
var query = from i in SFC.Supplies_ReceiveTrans 
            orderby i.Poprctnm descending 
            select new { RR = i.Poprctnm };
```

Result:

```
RR-01,
RR-01, 
RR-02, 
RR-02, 
RR-02, 
RR-TEST, 
RR-TEST,
```

How do i group RR in this kind of statement

Result:

```
RR-01,
RR-02, 
RR-TEST
```

---

just a few modification to ask if is it possible to do this one or what you have in your mind? Sorry for asking too much just really interested in learning more on linq.. how do i convert it into string coz its showing true or false.. boolean statement

```
var query = SFC.Supplies_ReceiveTrans.Select(s =>
s.Poprctnm.StartsWith(p))
.Distinct()
.OrderBy(p => p)
.Select(p => new { RR = p })
.Take(10);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [**`Distinct`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.distinct.aspx) or [**`GroupBy`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.groupby.aspx) methods in this case

```
var query = SFC.Supplies_ReceiveTrans.Select(s=> s.Poprctnm)
            .Distinct()
            .OrderByDescending(p => p)
            .Select(p=> new { RR = p });
```

if you use `OrderByDescending` then the result will be

```
RR-TEST 
RR-02 
RR-01
```

But I think you want `OrderBy` then the result will be

```
RR-01 
RR-02 
RR-TEST
```

So try below

```
var query = SFC.Supplies_ReceiveTrans.Select(s=> s.Poprctnm)
            .Distinct()
            .OrderBy(p => p)
            .Select(p=> new { RR = p });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var query = SFC.Supplies_ReceiveTrans
            .GroupBy(x=>x.Poprctnm)
            .Select(g=>g.First())
            .OrderByDescending(x=>x.Poprctnm)
            .Select(x=>new { RR = x.Poprctnm });
```

If you want to get `result` as group:

```
var query = SFC.Supplies_ReceiveTrans
            .GroupBy(x=>x.Poprctnm)
            .OrderByDescending(g=>g.Key);
```

Comment: @MikSkywalker which code? the first shouldn't be as you said.

Answer (score 1):

```
var result = SFC.Supplies_ReceiveTrans
                     .Select(x => new { RR = x.Poprctnm })
                     .Distinct()
                     .OrderByDescending(x => x.Poprctnm);
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need [Distinct](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.distinct.aspx) here, not group

```
var query = SFC.Supplies_ReceiveTrans
               .Select(x => new {RR = i.Poprctnm})
               .Distinct()
               .OrderByDescending(i => i);
```